# Is phonegap config.xml file support splash video instead of splash png? 

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

I have done application using sencha touch2, **using phone gap build i am packaging these files.** Right now i am able to show splash .png image during launching appication. But i need to show splash video to user while launching application. So i have added in place of source image path added video path not getting splash video. **I want to know about is phone-gap  support splash video or not?.** if it support means which type video format it will support. Can any tell me how to achieve this one.

**Here is code for splash image: Config.xml(Working)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.phonegap.example"
        versionCode="10" 
        version   = "1.0.0">
    <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->
    <name>ABC</name>
<gap:splash src="resources/splash/def.png" width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="resources/splash/def.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<icon src="resources/icons/xyz.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />
<icon src="resources/icons/xyz.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" width="100"  height="100"/> 
</widget>
```

**Here is code for Splash video: config.xml (Not working)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.phonegap.example"
        versionCode="10" 
        version   = "1.0.0">
    <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->
    <name>ABC</name>
<gap:splash src="resources/splash/AVIFile.avi.mp4" width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="resources/splash/AVIFile.avi.mp4" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<icon src="resources/icons/xyz.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />
<icon src="resources/icons/xyz.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" width="100"  height="100"/> 
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.media.myappindia"
        version   = "2.0.1">
    <title>myappindia</title>   
    <name>myappindia</name>

    <description>
        myappindia - my 1st app
    </description>

    <author href="http://www.myappindia.com/" email="android@myappindia.com">
        myappindia Team
    </author>

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.0.0" />
    <preference name="orientation"      value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device"    value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen"       value="false" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />

    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />

    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"         gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"    gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone" />

    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```